Selecting cell in google sheets to edit data input
How to select a column to edit in google sheets on macbook
As i tried in google sheet ,i can't edit the cell input.My cell get selected and after that it changes its position.There is no option for selecting and edit as such in MS Excel.In MS Excel when we double tap on cell we can edit the data .

This sounds like something you should ask someone to help you with in person. People on the internet probably won't be much help.
